# Disable some posting options in Facebook Sharer

Tags: facebook-sharer, posting

I wish to limit the posting options available in the Facebook sharer (www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php) so that users can't share on a friend's wall or in a group. I do not wish to use the Send button.

Is there a way of disabling these options?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to disable those options - I can't even think of why you'd want to do that - surely the aim of the button is to get users to share your content with their friends if they want to?